# Syntax error creating event; query works fine standalone

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create event on MYSQL Database. When I run query that creates EVENT SCHEDULE I got this error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

Wired thing is that when I run query inside EVENT SCHEDULE, it runs OK without any errors:

this is code that I am using

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `updateGoals` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 20 MINUTE STARTS '2015-01-01 00:01:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN

UPDATE `scores` SET `goals`='0'
WHERE `goals` >'0'
AND
( `PROCESS_DESC` LIKE '%No Goals%'
OR `PROCESS_DESC` LIKE '%NG %'
OR `PROCESS_DESC` LIKE '%Goals 0%');

END$$
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inside Event Schedule"?

Comment: @JayBlanchard when I run UPDATE Query outside of this EVENT it runs ok. I.E. When I run standalone query with one that I am using in EVENT, it runs ok

Comment: My understanding of procedure creation is limited but do you not need to start with `DELIMITER $$` if you're using that end line?

Comment: @Bulk without DEFINIER and END I got error so I checked some tutorials and I got this syntax that I am using now.

Comment: Try adding `DELIMITER $$` as the first line, see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, or remove the delimiter at the end. A nice validator can be found here: http://nl.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want. This delimiter stuff is nasty and confusing.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
       EVENT `updateGoals` 
          ON SCHEDULE EVERY 20 MINUTE 
      STARTS '2015-01-01 00:01:00' 
          ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
  DO BEGIN

    UPDATE `scores` SET `goals`='0'
     WHERE `goals` >'0'
      AND
           ( `PROCESS_DESC` LIKE '%No Goals%'
          OR `PROCESS_DESC` LIKE '%NG %'
          OR `PROCESS_DESC` LIKE '%Goals 0%');

END$$
```

You have noticed that your event will only run once, right? It says `ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE`.

If you want the event to stay around and keep running on schedule until you `DROP` it, use `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` instead.

Comment: I want to run it every 20 minutes. Do I need to delete ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE.?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I use your code it will run every 20 minutes until I DROP it ?

Comment: Yes, it will run every 20 minutes until you drop it explicitly.